# Debian 10 fails to manage laptop battery (was working fine few days ago)

Tags: debian, laptop, acpid

Debian 10 fails to manage laptop battery (was working fine few days ago).

is battery still detected ? :

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                G750-59
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 28 Aug 2020 08:43:24 PM CEST (17 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0.12 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         8.3 Wh
    energy-full-design:  89.208 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             15.12 V
    percentage:          1%
    capacity:            9.3041%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1598640204  1.000   charging
```

so it is ok
acpi & xfce-power-manager & upower services are up & running

Battery is now so low I cannot even unplug the power-plug adapter without crashing the laptop.

What can I do / check to investigate ? (*I don't think battery is dead until last week I used the laptop for about 2hours on battery*). So I think it is 90% sure pure software issue (*I also remember I did a big updates/upgrades on last monday*).

Comment: Do you have any LEDs on the laptop that could show you if the battery is actually getting charged or not? How old is the laptop/battery?

Comment: hello, yes I have one & it is like "charging", the battery is about 2 years old & the laptop about 4.  If I unplug the battery & measure it output pins it seems that I got around 15v other pins combinations seem to be used for something else (regulation/?)

Comment: I've expect it to be a hardware issue (i.e. battery is dead). Moreover, look at the `energy-full` and `energy-full-design` values. The battery seems to have dropped to ~10% of it's capacity, or at least that's what the battery controller believes. I had a similar experience in the past replacing my HP battery with a cheap chinese one.

Comment: seeing the nearly cheap price of a brand new official battery I'll get one & try to replace it / if it continues it is software if not the previous bat is faulty for any reason... heat protection detectin fail or anything else .....   I will want few days to recieve the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I received yesterday  morning the new one ;

plugged it in & wait for it to fill to 100% , I unplug the laptop, all is OK
detection / battery use and so on....

For testing, I plugged again the old battery, this time it charged to about 90% does not seem to accept charging more, so I unplugged the laptop for chronometer test : it lost 50% energy in 1h07,

I plugged again the new one & chronometer a 50% energy loss in 1h41.

I really can conclude the old one is still working fine, but was in a fail state that cannot be restored as ok until a battery detected as OK was plugged in place.

Then I did also ask about that issue to electronic hobbyists friend (*more experienced than myself on that point*), so wa guess there is in the battery a BMS (*Battery management system*) & maybe also a *temperature sensor* & *other security stuff* like *internal load-balancing* and so on...

We think one of those was back ok but just below the good value to be detected as good by a ADC (*imagine it need 4.5volts to be ok and it delivered 4.3volts to be transformed by the ADC as a TRUE/OK status byte*)

It looks to be the root cause. So the Old battery is still working fine but needed both hardware DAC can detect it as good and software side to flush stored "OK" state from files. Both seem to have been done while detecting the new battery.

So for now
The new battery will be the main one, and I keep the old one as a rescue one.